# Как вывести легенду в графике трёх переменных?

Tags: python, график

Как вывести цвета точек в легенде
и номера этих цветов (1 и 2 в моём случае) рядом?
После ответа на мой вопрос вот так заработало:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2.5,5],
                   'b':[0,1.5,3],
                   'c':[1,2,2]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(df.a, df.b, c=df.c)
legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), title="Classes")
ax.add_artist(legend1)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Тут посмотрите https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось.